# Parallel execution of independent Pig code blocks

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I filtered a pig data set based on some criteria as per below :

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage() as (f1:int,f2:int,f3:int,...);
G1 = FILTER A BY f1<0;
G2 = FILTER A BY (f1+f2)>0;
```

Now, the above two filtered data sets are processed and the outputs are stored using a STORE statement.

```
B = FOREACH G1 GENERATE ...
STORE B INTO 'location1'
C = FOREACH G2 GENERATE ...
STORE C INTO 'location2'
```

As both B and C are completely independent, and are generated by processing completely independent datasets G1 and G2, why are these two operations not running in parallel?

They are triggered in a sequential manner, at each STORE statement. As per my understanding, with multi-query execution enabled, shouldn't these two code blocks be run in parallel? If this is not possible, is there a way I can make these operations run in parallel, as this is taking a lot of time.

Comment: why do you think this is the case ? AFAIK pig will optimize it and will run in parallel

Comment: @Mzf When I run the script, I see two different sets of MR jobs in the logs, that are triggered sequentially. Also, the process overall is very slow due to this.

Comment: Is is significantly faster if you've just execute one of the STORE statement?

Comment: @kecso, yes it is. In fact, I divided the code into 5 different pig scripts(there were 5 store statements) and ran all of them in parallel through a shell script, and it takes considerably less time now. I just need to know why they are not running in parallel when in one pig script only.

Comment: I assue you've already read this doc: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/perf.html#multi-query-execution